# Calling ReferenceContainer or ReferenceBlock into phtml file

Tags: magento2.3, xml, phtml, magento2.3.4

I am trying to call Template into list.phtml, this file is categories list file, here is the ReferenceBlock and ReferenceContainer code in xml file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Devops\DropInCargo\Block\Product\View" name="drop.in.cargo.addtocart.popup" template="Devops_DropInCargo::product/view/addtocart/popup.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pickup.in.cargo.addtocart.popup.areas" template="Devops_DropInCargo::product/view/addtocart/popup/areas.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pickup.in.store.addtocart.popup.stores.list" template="Convert_PickupInStore::product/view/addtocart/popup/areas-list.phtml" />
        </block>

        <block class="Devops\DropInCargo\Block\Product\View" name="drop.in.cargo.addtocart.cart" template="Devops_DropInCargo::product/view/addtocart/cart.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

This is available in

```
 Vendor\Devops\module-DropInCargo\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

This shows the source in product page of magento 2 at the end before body ends. Now same code i want to show into list.phtml

```
 app\design\frontend\Devops\giga\design\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show your template in the product view page.

Looking at your layout file, you should be calling this:

```
$block->getChildHtml('drop.in.cargo.addtocart.popup')
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Then you should create new layout file:

`app\design\frontend\Devops\giga\design\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml`

with your content.

Comment: want to call template into product list page ( categories )

Comment: check my update.

Comment: i did created new layout file with same code from catalog_product_view.xml, but category page went empty, tried it with reducing code as well, but still page goes empty.

Comment: I did included template with <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Devops_DropInCargo::product/view/addtocart/popup.phtml')); ?>

but how to include block with sub and another sub block ? if you see above i did update code!

Comment: Check the error logs. You may need to change the blocks in your layout. For ex. `Devops\DropInCargo\Block\Product\View` class may not be compatible to go to category layout.